# Extracting a simple value from a JSON response in VBA

Tags: vba, libreoffice-calc

I am trying to get a simple response from a website and want to return a value into a field.

the json looks similar to this:
https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=38.725&lng=-9.355&date=2023-08-07

```
{"results":{"sunrise":"5:42:35 AM","sunset":"7:43:53 PM","solar_noon":"12:43:14 PM","day_length":"14:01:18","civil_twilight_begin":"5:14:59 AM","civil_twilight_end":"8:11:30 PM","nautical_twilight_begin":"4:39:34 AM","nautical_twilight_end":"8:46:54 PM","astronomical_twilight_begin":"4:01:24 AM","astronomical_twilight_end":"9:25:04 PM"},"status":"OK"}
```

I have written (found here) a function to get this data:

```
Function GetSun(lat,lon As Double, dateinput As Date) As String
Dim url as String
url = "https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=" & lat & "&lng=" & lon & "&date=" & dateinput

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim funtionAccess As Object
functionAccess = createUnoService("com.sun.star.sheet.FunctionAccess")

GetSun = functionAccess.callFunction("WEBSERVICE",Array(url))

Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
GetSun = "Error " & Err
End Function
```

In the cell it now has:

C12 = the latitude information

C13 = the longitude information

B6 = the date

```
=GETSUN(C12,C13,B6)
```

But what I would like is: (where I can define the returned field)

```
=GETSUN(C12,C13,B6,sunrise)
```

to return:

```
5:42:35 AM
```

And

```
=GETSUN(C12,C13,B6,sunset)
```

to return:

```
7:43:53 PM
```

If it matters: libreoffice calc on a linux mint laptop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass your Json string to two helper functions that use `Split` to extract the values:

```vb
Public Function GetSunrise(ByVal SunData As String) As String

    GetSunrise = Split(Split(SunData, """sunrise"":""", 2)(1), """,""", 2)(0)

End Function

Public Function GetSunset(ByVal SunData As String) As String

    GetSunset = Split(Split(SunData, """sunset"":""", 2)(1), """,""", 2)(0)

End Function
```

Test/output:

```vb
Sunrise = GetSunrise(s)
? Sunrise
5:42:35 AM

Sunset = GetSunset(s)
? Sunset
7:43:53 PM
```

**Addendum**:

For returning true date values:

```vb
Public Function GetSunrise(ByVal SunData As String) As Date

    GetSunrise = CDate(Split(Split(SunData, """sunrise"":""", 2)(1), """,""", 2)(0))

End Function

Public Function GetSunset(ByVal SunData As String) As Date

    GetSunset = CDate(Split(Split(SunData, """sunset"":""", 2)(1), """,""", 2)(0))

End Function
```

Test/output:

```vb
Sunrise = GetSunrise(s)
? Sunrise
05:42:35 

Sunset = GetSunset(s)
? Sunset
19:43:53
```

Comment: Perfect. Incorporated that into the original

Comment: Is there a way to format that to a proper time format? something I can calculate with?

Comment: Indeed. See addendum, please.

Comment: I found timevalue to do a better job

Answer (score 0):

Regex provides an option to extract both sunrise and sunset in one function.
Note: I'm not sure if libreoffice calc on a linux mint support RegExp.

```vb
Sub GetSunriseSunset()
    Dim url As String
    Dim httpRequest As Object
    Dim responseText As String
    url = "https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=38.725&lng=-9.355&date=2023-08-07"
    Set httpRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    httpRequest.Open "GET", url, False
    httpRequest.send
    responseText = httpRequest.responseText
'    Debug.Print responseText
    Set httpRequest = Nothing
    Debug.Print GetTime(responseText, "sunrise")
    Debug.Print GetTime(responseText, "sunset")
End Sub

Function GetTime(responseText, sMode)
    Dim objRegExp As Object
    Dim objMatch As Object
    Dim sTime As String
    Set objRegExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With objRegExp
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = Replace("@"":""([\d: AMP]+)", "@", sMode)
        Set objMatch = .Execute(responseText)
        If objMatch.Count > 0 Then
            sTime = objMatch(0).submatches(0)
        End If
    End With
    GetTime = sTime
    Set objRegExp = Nothing
    Set objMatch = Nothing
End Function
```

---

Integrated udf as below, get http request and regexp need to be updated for libreoffice calc on a linux mint.

> RegExp sample code for LO calc  https://gist.github.com/kbloom/757999

```vb
Function GetTime(lat As Double, lng As Double, dateinput As Date, sMode As String) As String
    Dim objRegExp As Object
    Dim objMatch As Object
    Dim sTime As String
    Dim url As String
    Dim httpRequest As Object
    Dim responseText As String
    url = "https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=" & lat & _
        "&lng=" & lng & "&date=" & Format(dateinput, "YYYY-mm-dd")
    Set httpRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    httpRequest.Open "GET", url, False
    httpRequest.send
    responseText = httpRequest.responseText
    Set objRegExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With objRegExp
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = Replace("@"":""([\d: AMP]+)", "@", sMode)
        Set objMatch = .Execute(responseText)
        If objMatch.Count > 0 Then
            sTime = objMatch(0).submatches(0)
        End If
    End With
    GetTime = sTime
    Set httpRequest = Nothing
    Set objRegExp = Nothing
    Set objMatch = Nothing
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: I always get a little lost (newby) when a sub gets involved. What would i put in the cell? =gettime(??)

Comment: I have updated code and uploaded a formula screenshot. Again, I am not sure if it is compatible with libreoffice calc.